# Is there a way to make a class recursive?

Tags: c++, class, recursion

So I would like to create a class that can have an object which type is itself.
Something like this:

```
class foo {

    foo Avalue = foo();
    foo Bvalue = foo();

    foo(int a, int b) {
        Avalue = goo(a);
        Bvalue = goo(b);
    }

    foo(foo a, int b) {
        Avalue = foo(a);
        Bvalue = goo(b);
    }

    foo(foo a, foo b) {
        Avalue = foo(a);
        Bvalue = foo(b);
    }
}

class goo : foo {

    int value;
}
```

so that I can have a recursive object that always terminates at "goo" objects.
Is there a way to make it?

Comment: If you have an instance of yourself, what happens when you try to create the first instance? It creates a nested instance, and then that one creates a nested instance. When does it stop?

Comment: What would be the size of an object of this class? It's not possible to calculate, so the compiler wouldn't know how much memory to allocate.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve with such (impossible)  construct?

Answer (score 6):

No. That is fundamentally impossible. Think about it: the class would have infinite size (well, unless it has no other members, I suppose, but then what does it do?), and no provable definition/identity.

You can store pointers to other `foo` objects, though. This works as long as not every `foo` has a member pointer that *does* point to another `foo`, or if the references form a cyclic dependency. Either way the compiler won't be diagnosing this in the way that it must with your attempted solution, but you can find trouble at runtime if you're not careful.

Your code suggests you're implementing a tree. This is the reason (well, one among a few, I suppose) that `std::map`, which is usually a tree, creates its nodes dynamically and links them with pointers. As does every linked list implementation.

Comment: As you said I do want to make a tree like structure, but I don't see why would it be infinite.  At the start you would have a `foo` object that can contain other `foo` objects or `goo` objects which can only store a value and can't store other instances of `foo` objects it would stop the recursive behavior. This would mean that that the main object would have a fix size.

Comment: @1mp0551bl3 A `goo` contains everything that a `foo` contains. That's the nature of inheritance.

Comment: S...Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 3):

The problem with that is that the `foo` inside `foo` would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain a `foo` which would contain...